# How to display a website and a button in one activity?

Tags: android, browser, layout, button

I'm making an application that contains button's and those buttons control an embedded browser. My problem is that I want to see the button's and the web page in the same layout, but when i click on a button this will open a web page and don't show the button, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem is that following a link opens the standard browser not your `WebView`, right ?

Add this to your `WebView` to change that behavior

```
// this is to prevent that when clicking a new URL from the displayed
// page the default web browser launches
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Layout that supports more than one child.  Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/ui/index.html)